# Looping Functoid with 856 Source

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, edi, biztalk-mapper, x12

I am trying to map from an 856 to an internal XML schema using the azure logic apps mapper(derived from BizTalk mapper).  The internal structure is relatively simple with a header record and a child detail record.  I have connected the HLLoop1 node to the ExDPASNItemTable node as shown in the screen shot.  However, only the first occurrence of the HL Loop is mapped.  This same technique works fine for an inbound 850 using a similar XML target.  Is there something special I should know about the 856 as a source that is different from the 850 ( I am aware of the hierarchical nature, but that is usually a challenge on the outbound side)?[image]

Comment: I can see nothing wrong on your current mapping. It should generate multiple ExDPASNItemTable if you have multiple source of HLLoop1.

Answer (score 0):

ExDPASNItemTable must be MaxOccurs = unbounded or otherwise >1.

The default is 1 and if that is the case, the mapper will not Loop over HLLoop1, regardless of the Looping Functoid.